# Deliver synchronized video to multiple tablets

Tags: android, ios, video, mobile, streaming

I have a live event where we'd like to explore the use of tablets (IOS/Android/Windows) attached to seats for the audience to access webpages and applications, but would also like the functionally to push a video stream to each tablet simultaneously and synchronized to an audio feed from the house PA.

So far, I haven't found any hardware/software combination that can pull this off yet. Obviously syncing video over IP isn't an easy task, but I'm hoping someone has a clue if it's possible or not. I'd also explore the use of tablets that have a hdmi/video input, but so far they don't seem to exist either.

Comment: Google Live Video Streaming, for example [this one](http://steveonjava.com/live-video-streaming-guide-part-1-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

Flash Media Server and use p2p.

Just realized your using IOS. IOS doesn't do Flash.